# "Unknown key: polymorphic" while running rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to implement a simple polymorphy. My goal is that user, group, and maybe other models can share a single pool of IDs, so that everything represents a `GlobalObject`. I built something like this:

- `global_object.rb` generated by `$ rails generate scaffold GlobalObject mode:integer`:

  ```
  class GlobalObject < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :mode
    has_many :identifyable, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy
  end
  ```
- `user.rb` generated by `$ rails generate scaffold User login password`:

  ```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :login, :password, :salt
    belongs_to :global_object, :as => :permittable
  end
  ```

And a group model would follow with a very similar structure. I didn't modify the migrate files from the db folder, but just executed `$ rake db:migrate`.

- `20131102224115_create_global_objects.rb`:

  ```
  class CreateGlobalObjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :global_objects do |t|
        t.integer :mode
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
  ```
- `20131102224332_create_users.rb`:

  ```
  class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      create_table :users do |t|
        t.string :login
        t.string :password
        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
  ```

When I execute `$ rake`, it shows two impressive traces with these beginnings:

```
(...)hash/keys.rb:51:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: polymorphic (ArgumentError)
    from /Users(...)
    ...

(...)hash/keys.rb:51:in `block in assert_valid_keys': Unknown key: polymorphic (ArgumentError)
    from /Users(...)
    ...
```

When I remove the `:polymorphic => true` in global_object.rb, the same errors occur, but instead of `Unknown key: polymorphic`, it says `Unknown key: as`. What is wrong?

Comment: At least you should point your class name, because i don't see any identifyable class. It should be `has_many :identifyable, :class_name => 'User', :polymorphic => true,...`

Comment: @zishe: the whole point of a polymorphic relationship is that it doesn't have to relate to a specific class...

Comment: ok, sorry for misunderstanding =)

Comment: From the looks of things, polymorphism is probably not what you really want. If you want to add common functionality to all your models, you could create a `module` and `include` it in each model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problems here:

- You are missing the polymorphic relationship columns in you migration that should refer to `identifyable_id` and `identifyable_type`.
- You are referring to the polymorphic association by different names - `identifyable` and `permittable`.
- Polymorphic relationships are meant to be set on the child elements (`belongs_to`) and referred to by multiple parent classes (`has_many`).  You have it the other way around which is not supported (and wouldn't really make sense from a modeling perspective).

It would be helpful to understand what a `GlobalObject` is meant to accomplish to help determine if polymorphic associations are the correct approach here.  But if you wanted to use them, you'd either need to make a `GlobalObject` belong_to identifyable (and add the necessary columns there), or you'd need to move it to the `User` and add the columns there.

Comment: Then I have to add `identifyable_id` and `identifyable_type` to the GlobalObject migration, right? Because GlobalObject can have many Users, but a User can only have a single GlobalObject. Later there can be also be a Group that has a single GlobalObject but the GlobalObject can have many Users and Groups.

Comment: Correct on all three points. I'm 99% sure the error is thrown because `:polymorphic` is not an option for `has_many` - just an option for `belongs_to`.

Comment: @Tygaz: No, this is not correct.  An entity supporting polymorphic associations _must_ use a `belongs_to` declaration to define the association.  This means that `GlobalObject` cannot 'have many' users as you have it setup.

Comment: @Tygaz it doesn't sound like you need polymorphism. Just have a global_object_id field on your User model and Group model. Then: user belongs_to global_object, group belongs_to global_object, and gobal_object has_many users and groups.

Comment: Aaah, right! Now I got it. I swapped the `belongs_to` and `has_many` in the files, corrected the `:permittable` (how stupid, thanks for noting that ^^'), added the id and type, re-migrated and now it works. Thank you so much :)
@tybro Well... this sounds good. I think, you're right. I'll test it ;)